# MYSQL Select query stuck in "Sending data"

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, database-optimization

I have an select query with about 1M records, I'm working on Magento 1.9 database.

```
    SELECT IF(sup_ap.is_percent = 1, TRUNCATE(mt.value + (mt.value * sup_ap.pricing_value / 100), 4),
          mt.value + SUM(sup_ap.pricing_value)) AS `value`,
       75                                       AS `attribute_id`,
       `supl`.`product_id`                      AS `entity_id`,
       `cs`.`store_id`
FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `mt`
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `sup_a` ON mt.entity_id = product_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `sup_ap`
                    ON sup_ap.product_super_attribute_id = sup_a.product_super_attribute_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `supl` ON mt.entity_id = supl.parent_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `pint`
                    ON pint.entity_id = supl.product_id and pint.attribute_id = sup_a.attribute_id and
                       pint.value = sup_ap.value_index
         INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.website_id = sup_ap.website_id
WHERE (mt.entity_id in (select product_id from catalog_product_super_attribute))
  AND (mt.attribute_id = '75')
GROUP BY `entity_id`, `cs`.`store_id`
LIMIT 500
```

My Explain:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                           | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                  | key                                                            | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | cs                              | index  | IDX_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID                                                                                                                                      | IDX_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID                                      | 2       | NULL                               |    7 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | sup_ap                          | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID_VAL_IDX_WS_ID,IDX_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_WEBSITE_ID | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_WEBSITE_ID         | 2       | cs.website_id                      |   11 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | sup_a                           | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID                                             | PRIMARY                                                        | 4       | sup_ap.product_super_attribute_id  |    1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | mt                              | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID                     | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID                  | 6       | sup_a.product_id,const             |    1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | catalog_product_super_attribute | ref    | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID                                                     | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID    | 4       | sup_a.product_id                   |    1 | Using index; FirstMatch(mt)                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | supl                            | ref    | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID                         | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID                       | 4       | sup_a.product_id                   |    4 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | pint                            | ref    | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID            | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID | 6       | supl.product_id,sup_a.attribute_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I have no experience about optimize the select query with stuck at **sending data**, I tried update the select query to this:

```
SELECT IF(sup_ap.is_percent = 1, TRUNCATE(mt.value + (mt.value * sup_ap.pricing_value / 100), 4),
          mt.value + SUM(sup_ap.pricing_value)) AS `value`,
       75                                       AS `attribute_id`,
       `supl`.`product_id`                      AS `entity_id`,
       `cs`.`store_id`
FROM (select entity_id, `value` from `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where attribute_id = '75') AS `mt`
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `sup_a` ON mt.entity_id = product_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `sup_ap`
                    ON sup_ap.product_super_attribute_id = sup_a.product_super_attribute_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `supl` ON mt.entity_id = supl.parent_id
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `pint`
                    ON pint.entity_id = supl.product_id and pint.attribute_id = sup_a.attribute_id and
                       pint.value = sup_ap.value_index
         INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.website_id = sup_ap.website_id
WHERE (sup_a.product_id is not null)
GROUP BY `entity_id`, `cs`.`store_id`
LIMIT 500;
```

New Explain:

```
+------+-------------+--------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                          | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                  | key                                                            | key_len | ref                                | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+--------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cs                             | index  | IDX_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID                                                                                                                                      | IDX_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID                                      | 2       | NULL                               |    7 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | sup_ap                         | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID_VAL_IDX_WS_ID,IDX_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_WEBSITE_ID | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_WEBSITE_ID         | 2       | cs.website_id                      |   11 |                                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | sup_a                          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID                                             | PRIMARY                                                        | 4       | sup_ap.product_super_attribute_id  |    1 | Using where                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | catalog_product_entity_decimal | ref    | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ENTITY_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID                     | UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID                  | 6       | sup_a.product_id,const             |    1 |                                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | supl                           | ref    | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID                         | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID                       | 4       | sup_a.product_id                   |    4 |                                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pint                           | ref    | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID            | UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID | 6       | supl.product_id,sup_a.attribute_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+--------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Update 1: Table Structors**

#### 1: catalog_product_entity_decimal;

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `value` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_ATTR_ID_STORE_ID` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DECIMAL_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_DEC_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28087876 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Decimal Attribute Backend Table'
```

#### 2: catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` (
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `product_super_attribute_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Super Attribute ID',
  `value_index` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value Index',
  `is_percent` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Percent',
  `pricing_value` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Pricing Value',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID_VAL_IDX_WS_ID` (`product_super_attribute_id`,`value_index`,`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID` (`product_super_attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRICING_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_PRICING_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CDE8813117106CFAA3AD209358F66332` FOREIGN KEY (`product_super_attribute_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_super_attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Super Attribute Pricing Table'
```

#### 3: catalog_product_super_link

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link` (
  `link_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Link ID',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID` (`product_id`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PARENT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Super Link Table'
```

#### 4: catalog_product_entity_int

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `entity_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36351339 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Integer Attribute Backend Table'
```

#### 5: core_store

```
CREATE TABLE `core_store` (
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Group Id',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Name',
  `sort_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Sort Order',
  `is_active` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Activity',
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_STORE_CODE` (`code`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_STORE_IS_ACTIVE_SORT_ORDER` (`is_active`,`sort_order`),
  KEY `IDX_CORE_STORE_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_STORE_GROUP_ID_CORE_STORE_GROUP_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `core_store_group` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_STORE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores'
```

Extremely grateful that you could take a moment to consider keep an eye on the issue above.

**Update 2**

I find out the problem that I have a join condition with 2 two columns has difference type.

```
pint.value = sup_ap.value_index
```

Comment: Query 1, try using an inner join instead of the left join and make the where clause simpler, to just `WHERE mt.attribute_id = '75'` looks to me as if that left join is being overridden by the where clause anyway. The number of rows shown in the explain plan is tiny, not sure optimisation is the issue.

Comment: Thank for the fast feedback, I have no idea too, can you please suggest me another ways to fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why such a query, with so little data should be stuck in "sending data". I'm also not familiar with Magneto and don't even know how that is relevant. I just don't see the issue as being one that is solved via query optimisation. Perhaps some dbms maintenance tasks are required - the row counts in the explain plan could be misleading maybe??? (i.e. sorry, but no solution from me)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there is a common mistake that is made is EAV schemas.

Comment: Oke @RickJames, I will send you soon,

Comment: Hi @RickJames I updated my question, added table structors.

Answer (score 1):

- I think you can get rid of `LEFT` because of `WHERE  (sup_a.product_id is not null)`
- Some composite (and covering) indexes:

  ```
  sup_a:  (product_id, attribute_id, product_super_attribute_id)
  pint:  (value, attribute_id, entity_id)
  supl:  (product_id, parent_id)
  mt:  (attribute_id, entity_id, value)  -- perhaps the most imporant
  ```

Also, ...

- Watch out when mixing numeric and string datatypes, where one is a constant:

  ```
   char_col = "123"    -- good
   char_col =  123     -- performs poorly (won't use index)
   int_col  =  123     -- good
   int_col  = "123"    -- this happens to be 'good'
   int_col  = "123ABC" -- may give strange results
  ```
- Make sure the `COLLATION` matches when comparing `VARCHARs`.

Comment: You means I should using inner join instead of left join on **sup_a**?

Comment: @HoangHieu - Yes.  And the `WHERE` clause has a test that invalidates `LEFT`.  That is, the Optimizer will change `LEFT` to `INNER` anyway.  Please run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ... ; SHOW WARNINGS;` to verify.

Comment: Hi @Rick James i find out the problem that I have a join condition with 2 two columns has difference type.

Comment: @HoangHieu - Sorry, I forgot to check that.  I added that and some other tips.